# CSS селектор предыдущего элемента

Tags: css

В `css` с помощью братских селекторов такие как `+` и `~` можно обратится к соседним блокам не выше уровнем и не ниже, но, обратиться можно лишь к следующему, есть ли возможность обратиться к предыдущему?

```css
p + span {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<span>Hello</span>
<p>World</p>
<span>!</span>
```

Вот пример, а мне нужно чтобы обращение было к предыдущему спану

Comment: Переименуйте тему вопроса так, что бы оно соответствовало вопросу, а не Вашему отношению к нему.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-selector - вот здесь перечислено много вариантов решающих ваш вопрос